# Using multiple conditions in a single line of CASE...WHEN statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way of using multiple conditions inside a single line of CASE...WHEN statement in MySQL?

For instance, I want to write a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT col1, col2,
CASE 
    WHEN ((condition1) AND (condition2)) THEN 1 ELSE 0
END as col3,
col4
FROM table1
```

How can I write a query similar to the above one appropriately in MySQL?

Comment: You write it exactly like you've shown. Did you run it?

Comment: Yes, I've run it and it says Syntax error near 'THEN 1 ELSE 0'.

Comment: This is valid syntax for MySQL, and should work, I just verified it with: SELECT col1, col2,
CASE 
    WHEN ((col1 > 0) AND (col2 > 0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0
END as col3,
col4
FROM (SELECT 1 as col1, 2 as col2, 4 as col4) foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL statement you have provided looks right. Another alternative would be using IF

```
SELECT col1, col2, IF((condition1) AND (condition2), 1, 0), col4 from table1;
```

For more help you could refer to : [MySQL Reference Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col1, col2,
CASE 
    WHEN (if(your_condition , 'true_Result' , 'False_result') AND if(your_condition , 'true_Result' , 'False_result')) THEN 1 ELSE 0
END as col3,
col4
FROM table1
```

Explanation: 
if(your_condition , 'true_Result' , 'False_result')
If your conditions becomes true, it would pick your value set in 'true_result', if condition is false, it would pick from 'false_Result'
Example: `if(sum(columnname)=0 , 1 , 0)` to check if a particular column contains all values as 0 or not.